# Testable matrix in python

Tags: python

I got an assignment about testing testable matrix. It says a boolean matrix is testable if the sums of rows and the sums of columns are even.

If there's only one bit wrong, than print "change bit(,)"

If more, print "Corrupt".

If it is testable, just print"OK".

At first, we have to input times of test case. And than we start to input the size of matrix(for example, if it was a 4x4 matrix, just input 4.) and our matrix itself.

Now I have no idea why it always runs well on my VS but wrong on Online Judge....

```
def check_once() :
    length=int(input())
    matrix=[]
    for b in range(length):
        line=input().split()
        for c in range(length):
            line[c]=int(line[c])
        matrix.append(line)

    result=True
    check_num1=0
    for x in range(length):
        n=0
        for y in range(length):
            n+=int(matrix[x][y])
        if n%2!=0 and check_num1==0:
            check_num1=x+1
        elif n%2!=0 and check_num1!=0:
            print("Corrupt")
            result=False 
            break

    if result==True:
        check_num2=0
        for y in range(length): 
            n=0
            for x in range(length):
                n+=int(matrix[x][y])
            if n%2!=0 and check_num2==0:
                check_num2=y+1
            elif n%2!=0 and check_num2!=0:
                print("Corrupt") 
                result=False
                break
       
    if result==True:
        if check_num1==0 and check_num2==0: 
            print("OK")
        elif check_num1!=0 and check_num2!=0: 
            print("Change bit",(check_num1,check_num2))

if __name__=="__main__":
    i=int(input())
    for a in range(i):
        check_once()
```

This is my sample input.

```
3
4
1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1
0 1 0 1
4
1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0
1 1 1 1
0 1 0 1
4
1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
0 1 0 1
```

This is my output.

```
OK
Change bit (2,3)
Corrupt
```

Comment: Welcome! Please see the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and include code you have so far.

Comment: The bit is wrong: python uses zero-based indexing

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hello! But I have already add one before output (check_num1=x+1), so I think it's not the problem QQ

Comment: You shouldn't be adding one. The second example should report (1,2), not (2,3)

Comment: @MadPhysicist But it's the sample output, which means our indicator hopes as to do so.

Comment: @Katie. Gotcha.

Comment: FWIW, your code seems fine to me. Do you know what fails exactly in the online version?

Comment: @MadPhysicist No, we are not allowed to see the exact data. And that's also what makes me confused! My output is totally the same with the sample, but OJ keeps saying it's wrong.

Comment: Does it tell you what type of test you failed? Perhaps timing or memory usage?